# How can I LEFT JOIN Count in Subquery

Tags: mysql

I have this query, it's not throwing any errors for me & each subquery is working as expected when ran by itself. When I run the whole thing, as follows, I only get  the columns: `post_title` & `views`

```
SELECT post_title, 
       views, 
       coupons_today, 
       coupons_lifetime, 
       coupons_remaining 
FROM   wp_posts p 
       LEFT JOIN wp_act ct --has views column
              ON ct . campaign_id = p . id 
       LEFT JOIN(SELECT Count(*)    AS coupons_today, 
                        campaign_id cid 
                 FROM   wp_act 
                 WHERE  date = CURRENT_DATE) AS act1 
              ON act1 . cid = p . id 
       LEFT JOIN(SELECT Count(*)    AS coupons_lifetime, 
                        campaign_id cid2 
                 FROM   wp_act) AS act2 
              ON act2 . cid2 = p . id 
       LEFT JOIN(SELECT Count(*)    AS coupons_remaining, 
                        campaign_id cid3 
                 FROM   wp_ac 
                 WHERE  status IS NULL) AS ac 
              ON p . id = ac . cid3 
WHERE  p . post_status = 'publish'
AND p . post_type = 'page'
AND p . ping_status = 'open';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
SELECT  p.post_title,
        ct.views, 
      ( SELECT  Count(*)
            FROM  wp_act
            WHERE  date = CURRENT_DATE
              AND  campaign_id = p.id 
      ) AS coupons_today, 
      ( SELECT  Count(*)
            FROM  wp_act
            WHERE  campaign_id = p.id 
      ) AS coupons_lifetime, 
      ( SELECT  Count(*)
            FROM  wp_ac
            WHERE  status IS NULL
              AND  campaign_id = p.id 
      ) AS coupons_remaining
    FROM  wp_posts p
    LEFT JOIN  wp_act ct  ON ct . campaign_id = p . id
    WHERE  p . post_status = 'publish'
      AND  p . post_type = 'page'
      AND  p . ping_status = 'open';
```

Comment: I just found the solution, unfortunately with yours I got: WordPress database error Operand should contain 1 column(s) for query

Comment: Just posted, any improvements welcomed, but it seems to be working as expected

Comment: Without my schema, it's hard to tell, but in `wp_act` columns are `campaign_id, date, views, coupons`. I do an `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` there (`views` or `coupons`+1). That the reasoning behind my edits. I'll continue to test, but I'm done for today...or yesterday. Thanks for your help!

Comment: ...maybe even impossible...especially with the original late night query (my bad!)

Comment: I saw the suggested (and rejected by others) edits to my solution.  I cannot judge which, if any, of the `COUNT(*)` should be changed as suggested.  @webaholik , I leave it up to you to judge.

Comment: I'll improve my question later today so the thread makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

With some help from a friend (thanks Swaroop) I ended up with this:

```
    SELECT    p.post_title,
      ct.views         AS views,
      ct.coupons       AS coupons_today,
      Sum(ctl.coupons) AS coupons_lifetime,
     (SELECT Count(*) FROM wp_ac WHERE c.campaign_id = p.id AND c.status IS NULL)
      AS coupons_remaining
    FROM wp_posts p
    LEFT JOIN wp_act ct  ON ct.campaign_id = p.id  AND ct.date = CURRENT_DATE
    LEFT JOIN wp_act ctl ON ctl.campaign_id = p.id
    WHERE p.post_status = 'publish'
      AND p.post_type = 'page'
      AND p.ping_status = 'open'
    GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: Double check the SUM() and COUNT(); the values may be higher than expected.

Comment: @RickJames You were absolutely right, my coupons remaining was off.